# Store static array used by a number of models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an application written in Laravel 5. I have a model `Product` which uses a table `products`.

In the table I want to store the product size. At the moment there are only two sizes: `M` and `L` which stand for Medium and Large.

An admin user is able to update the size so I will have a dropdown for this. My question is; what is the best way to store the size data?

1. Add static array the Product Model
2. Create a Size Model with database with a relationship
3. Create a Size Model with no database but a static array
4. Add the array to config file

It is possible that more sizes will be introduced and that other models will use them. I'm thinking it's fine to just add as a static array to the Product model.

Comment: Will your one product have only one size or multiple sizes?

Comment: Each product will only have one size

Comment: I will recommend your second option Create a Size Model with database with a relationship. It would be better if you will have more sizes in table in future. You dont need to hardcode anything.

Comment: You can check my answer as well.

Comment: If you want the app admin to be able to create/delete size options, or size options changes frequently; create a table for it. But adding simply a enum column to the products table is simple and efficient to query. This case does not have an analytic solution, you should consider trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `ProductSize` model and define its relationships accordingly.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductSize::class); 
    }
}

class ProductSize extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class); 
    }
}
```

To access a product's sizes, you could just do:

```
Product::find(1)->sizes;
```

I don't know your use case and I would think that while it can work with an array, it just doesn't make sense to do it.

Also, not all products may be available in all the sizes. How would you take care of this scenario with an array? Additionally, keeping things in the database makes querying, producing reports etc much easier.

Answer (score 0):

As per your goal you can create 2 models as below and make a relationship for it.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    //You have only one size for each product
    public function size()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Size::class);
    }
}

class Size extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```